# Editing/filtering data table on power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Currently I have a table with 2 columns from a SharePoint list on power apps. For example:

| Feature | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| B | 3 |

Is there a way to filter the feature to be the horizontal column header and the Name to be the vertical row header and have them so that the features and names don't repeat, i.e. something like this?

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes |  |
| 2 |  |  | Yes |
| 3 |  | Yes |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can group the collection based on "Feature" column using **GroupBy** function.

For example:

I have this collection:

```
ClearCollect(
    colFeaturesList,
    {
        Feature: "A",
        Name: 1
    },
    {
        Feature: "B",
        Name: 1
    },
    {
        Feature: "C",
        Name: 2
    },
    {
        Feature: "B",
        Name: 3
    }
)
```

Then I can group it by feature name like:

```
ClearCollect(colGBFeatures, GroupBy(colFeaturesList, "Feature", "Names"))
```

Then I added one vertical gallery with single label (Title only layout) & set  "items" property of gallery to `colGBFeatures` and "Text" property of label control to:

```
ThisItem.Feature
```

Then I added nested gallery inside above gallery, set "items" property of gallery to `ThisItem.Names` and "Text" property of label control to:

```
ThisItem.Name
```

Here's the output:

[image]

**Note**: You can use the grouped collection and design UI as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to make it into the 2nd table example I had given, only because, I have around 15 features and probably more than 100 names so it might not look too neat this way.

Comment: You might not be able to fit the 15 features horizontally in screen as well. You can try using combination of horizontal and vertical gallery.